# Why mongoose sets count as last document but in my Schema is second document

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose-schema

```
let UserSchema = new Schema({

  username: String,
  count: Number,
  log: [{

    _id: false,
    description: String,
    duration: Number,
    date: String

  }],
   
},
{ versionKey: false })

let User = mongoose.model("User", UserSchema)
```

and output code

```
app.get('/api/users/:id?/logs', (req,res) => {

   var id = req.params.id

   User.find(
      {_id: id},
      (err, result) =>
        {
          if (err) throw err
          res.json(result)
        }
    )

})
```

output example

> [{"_id":"640cfc22471cdd96f98f9205","username":"test2","log":[{"description":"test3","duration":60,"date":"Mon Apr 03 2023"}],"count":1}]

as you see hire, count is printed last but i want it third

i tried switching in the schema but nothing changed

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB stored the document according the fields set in the MongoDB collection not as the fields defined in the schema.

if you wanted to store as schema then use the index while defining the schema like:

```
const mySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  title: { type: String, index: 0 },
  count: { type: Number, index: 1 }
});
```